# Matrix will not allow me to use sample()

Tags: r

So the code:

```
 matrix(apply(hand, 1, sample(1:5,5,replace=TRUE)),byrow=TRUE, nrow=5)
```

Gives me the error message "Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE)' is not a function, character or symbol"

It seems counter-intuitive because sample() is a function??

Note: hand is itself a matrix of the same size of nrow=5, which I would like to fill by taking sample()

Comment: `sample` is a function. `sample(1:5,5,replace=TRUE)` is not - it is a vector of 5 numbers. Type them both into the console and hit enter to see what I mean.

Comment: so how would I fill in a matrix with the vector produced by sample(1:5,5,replace=TRUE)

Comment: Since you're doing sample by replacement, just grab 25 values and then put it in a matrix - `matrix(sample(1:5, 25, replace=TRUE), nrow=5)`